# Use of Elastic IP address in Route 53 not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I am trying to change which instance my A record in Route 53 points to.

For my domain app.mydomain.com the A record in Route 53 currently points to the elastic IP of one of my two instances (e.g. 11.22.33.44). This works fine. If I enter app.mydomain.com in a browser I get taken to the instance.

I have created a new elastic IP address for the other instance that I have in EC2 and put this IP address in the Route 53 A record in place of 11.22.33.44. Although the instance is working fine (i.e. I can enter mysecondinstance.elasticbeanstalk.com in a browser and get to see what I expect) if I enter app.mydomain.com in a browser the connection times out. I have left it over an hour since I made the change in Route 53.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? I guess I am missing an important step somewhere?

Comment: the whole setup sounds off. what are you trying to achieve? why are you trying to access the elastic beanstalk instances instead of the load balancer? is this a webapp?

Comment: I took this project over from someone with no documentation so am having to work out what is going on as best I can. The instances are for a mobile app.

Comment: well it sounds like you're using it wrong. the mobile app should connect to the elastic beanstalk cname (myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com)

Comment: No I can't map the app to a specific EB instance as then I would have to change the app when the instance changes. The app is mapped to a url and Route 53 maps the url to an instance. That makes more sense as the app is then not dependant on where the server code is located.

Comment: Nope, the EB URL stays the same. meaning - myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com will never change. it's the instances that it directs traffic to that may change. if your app sends requests to myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com it is guaranteed that it will never change. Now for route 53 - that should only provide you with a mean to map (cname) myapp.mydomain.com to myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com (to get a personal URL). It is wrong to point directly to the servers, only elasticbeanstalk should direct traffic directly to the server.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation that describes this? It does sound like the solution I need :)

Comment: I've posted an answer. have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk architecture ([read this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.architecture.html)) provides a much simpler approach. You don't need to point your route 53 URL to the internal server, but rather to the Elastic Beanstalk load balancer. The latter will take care of routing traffic to the internal servers, and will replace them seamlessly in case of failure.
So to address your case - simply point your route 53 A record to the Elastic Beanstalk load balancer ([elaborated here](http://www.objectliteral.com/custom-domain-elastic-beanstalk/)).

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question, but perhaps an interesting suggestions.

Instead of changing the A record (which takes time to propagate), you could reassociate the Elastic IP address to your new instance. This should only take a second or 5 and all traffic will automatically go to your new instance.

The only problem is that existing connections will be terminated, so if you do this for anything other than http(s) traffic, be careful that you close all connections!